# Creating a Class to create skills for an RPG

Tags: vb.net, class, parameters

I am creating a sort of small RPG style game. at this point i have attempted to create 3 skills. heal, strike, and finisher, as a test. heal gives +15 HP, strike deals 15dmg, and finisher deals 25dmg with 15 recoil damage. i have coded these skills all separately. i was later told that using a "class" i can create a parant of what a skill should have, and its properties, but i am not sure how to use this in my case. i have searched for a full day on classes, but havent found what would apply to my situation. any help would be appreciated on how i cancreate a class holding parameters such as MAna needed, damage dealt, hp regenerate, crit rate bonus, level needed, and so forth. after i get a just of how it should look , i should be able to do it on my own. i can send some of my code for my skills if that is of any help.

```
Public Class Skill

Private Sub btnSHeal_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSHeal.Click
    SkillSelected = 1
End Sub

Private Sub btnSStrike_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSStrike.Click
    SkillSelected = 2
End Sub

Private Sub btnSFinisher_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSFinisher.Click
    'attack += 25
    'recoil = 15
    SkillSelected = 3
End Sub

Private Sub Skill_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If lvl >= 1 Then
        btnSStrike.Enabled = True
    Else
        btnSStrike.Enabled = False
    End If
    If lvl >= 1 Then
        btnSFinisher.Enabled = True
    Else
        btnSFinisher.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    ' not sure what the old code was doing

    Timer2.Stop() ' stop the attacks

    Battle.MonsterAttacks(health, mattack, CritRate, Defence)
    Battle.HPBarsAlter(mhealth, health)
    Battle.MobDeath(mhealth, MobNumber)

End Sub

Sub Heal(ByRef Mana As Integer, ByRef health As Integer)
    If Mana > 0 And lvl >= 1 Then
        health += 25
        Mana -= 15
        Call Battle.HPBarsAlter(mhealth, health)
        Call Battle.textShiftUp(numlines)

        Timer2.Interval = 1500
        Timer2.Start()
    Else
        Battle.TextBox.Text = Battle.TextBox.Text & vbNewLine & "You Do NOT have enough Mana for this Skill!"
    End If
End Sub
Sub Strike(ByRef Mana As Integer, ByRef attack As Integer)
    If Mana > 0 And lvl >= 2 Then
        attack = Sattack
        Mana -= 15
        Call Battle.PlayerAttacks(mhealth, Sattack)
        Call Battle.HPBarsAlter(mhealth, health)
        Call Battle.textShiftUp(numlines)

        Timer2.Interval = 1500
        Timer2.Start()
    ElseIf Mana > 0 Then
        Battle.TextBox.Text = Battle.TextBox.Text & vbNewLine & "You Do NOT have enough Mana for this Skill!"
    ElseIf lvl < 2 Then
        Battle.TextBox.Text = Battle.TextBox.Text & vbNewLine & "You Are not level 2!"
    End If
End Sub
Sub Finisher(ByRef Mana As Integer, ByRef attack As Integer, ByRef recoil As Integer)
    If Mana > 0 And lvl >= 4 Then
        Sattack = attack + 25
        Mana -= 30
        recoil = 15

        Call Battle.PlayerAttacks(mhealth, Sattack)
        Call Battle.HPBarsAlter(mhealth, health)
        Call Battle.textShiftUp(numlines)
        health -= recoil
        Battle.TextBox.Text = Battle.TextBox.Text & vbNewLine & "You Do Took " & recoil & " recoil Damage"
        Timer2.Interval = 1500
        Timer2.Start()
    ElseIf Mana > 0 Then
        Battle.TextBox.Text = Battle.TextBox.Text & vbNewLine & "You Do NOT have enough Mana for this Skill!"
    ElseIf lvl < 2 Then
        Battle.TextBox.Text = Battle.TextBox.Text & vbNewLine & "You Are not level 4!"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button10_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
    Using SkillForm As New HotKeyAdd()
        SkillForm.ShowDialog()
    End Using
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Psst. `btnSStrike.Enabled = lvl >= 1`

Comment: You have two `If` statement that check a condition. If the condition is `True`, they set something to `True`. If the condition is `False`, they set something to `False`. See the redundancy? You can just set that thing to the condition directly; parentheses for clarity, if you like: `btnSFinisher.Enabled = (lvl >= 1)`

Comment: so by using that, i can set it to enabled onnly if lvl is greater than 1?

Comment: what is mana?  FWIW with class props a lot of your Subs go away.  WHen the Monster is Attacked and suffers damage, adjusting the HP bar would be part of the job of the 'HP Property'.  It results in less code...all the skills which affect HP would update the HP bar from the base class ('Skill' below) automatically.  When you build a new Skill, lots of code is already in place :)

Comment: mana is MP, like that blue bar in games, the user needs MP in order to use a skill. how would i get it to adjust the hp using an hp property in the monster class?